# firebase, how i get a specific structure depending on the user id

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

i would like to get the structure **info** depending on the id:

[image: My database]

like in sql one to many, getting all the events that the user created and then displays to edit or delete them

```
db.ref( 'events/' ).once( 'value', ( snapshot ) => {
  console.log( snapshot.val() );
  res.render( 'event', { event : true, body : snapshot.val() } );
});`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all child nodes of `events` that have a certain value for their ID property, you can use something like this:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref("events")
  .orderByChild("id")
  .equalTo("BMhV07XE8dcUsDCZKMOS9y76EGY")
  .once("value")
  .then((results) => {
    results.forEach((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.child("id").val());
    });
  })
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).